# Priority matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, while-loop

I have the follow task:

I do have a table as we can see bellow:
[image]

As you can see, I have 10 columns.

I need to create a new column "WhseFrom" which will return the value name of one of the 7 (AH,AYC,MAEG,MAR,ROT,WITZ,BUD) columnS  based on the such prioritization conditions that comes from the idea behind this table:

[image]

Then, the values that shouold contain on this new column "Pull2" should be based on the conditions.

As example, while the store == BUD, the tracker data should check while Pull column is higher than 0, if the quantity in the WHSE== WITZ is enough(equal or higher) than in the Pull column, if yes, it should break the search and return the Pull value, but if not, the tracker function sholuld continue and so check the quantities in the WHSE== ROT, and if still not enough, continue and check on the follow WHSE which follow from the column list of priorization.

This scenario must be done also for all the other store=='WHSE'.

Any idea or suggestions would be very appreciate.

I was trying to create the follow code:

```
def findQty(row):
while row['store']== 'BUD' and row['Pull'] > 0:
    if row['Pull'] >= row['ROT']:
        return row['Pull']
        continue 
    else:
        if row['Pull'] < row['ROT']:
            return (row['WITZ'] - row['Pull'])
            break #maybe here include other columns
        else: 
            pass
 else:
    pass

while row['store']== 'WITZ' and row['Pull'] > 0:
    if row['Pull'] >= row['WITZ']:
        return row['Pull']
        continue
    else:
        if row['Pull'] < row['WITZ']:
            return (row['WITZ'] - row['Pull'])
            break 
        else:
            pass
else:
    pass

while row['store']== 'MAR' and row['Pull'] > 0:
    if row['Pull'] >= row['WITZ']:
        return row['Pull']
        continue
    else:
        if row['Pull'] < row['WITZ']:
            return (row['WITZ'] - row['Pull'])
            break 
        else:
            pass            
else:
    pass

while row['store']== 'ROT'  and row['Pull'] > 0:
    if row['Pull'] >= row['WITZ']:
        return row['Pull']
        continue
    else:
        if row['Pull'] < row['WITZ']:
            return (row['WITZ'] - row['Pull'])
            break 
        else:
            pass            
else:
    pass

while row['store']== 'MAEG'  and row['Pull'] > 0:
    if row['Pull'] >= row['ROT']:
        return row['Pull']
        continue
    else:
        if row['Pull'] < row['ROT']:
            return (row['WITZ'] - row['Pull'])
            break
        else:
            pass        
else:
    pass

 while row['store']== 'AYC' and row['Pull'] > 0:
    if row['Pull'] >= row['WITZ']:
        return row['Pull']
        continue
    elif row['Pull'] < row['WITZ']:
        return (row['WITZ'] - row['Pull'])
        break
```

But as you can see, still missing the possibilites once the first condition for the store in question is being tracked.

Please, I need suggestion in how it would be developed it on Python.

For the data manipulation, follow a sample to create the "table A" bellow:

```
import pandas as pd
tabela = [ (8489,'BUD', 175,0,0,0,0,0,1522,0 )]
tabeladf = pd.DataFrame(tabela)
tabeladf

tabeladf.columns = ['PNO','store', 'Pull', 'ADH','AYC', 
'MAEG','MAR','ROT', 'WITZ','BUD' ]
tabeladf

def findQty(row):
while row['store']== 'BUD' and row['Pull'] > 0:
    if row['Pull'] >= row['ROT']:
        return row['Pull']
        continue 
    else:
        if row['Pull'] < row['ROT']:
            return (row['WITZ'] - row['Pull'])
            break #maybe here include other columns
        else: 
            pass


tabeladf['WhseFrom'] = tabeladf.apply(findQty, axis=1)
tabeladf
```

So the expected column to be returned is this WHSEFrom, which will check in each row if for the store==BUD we do have enough quantity in the Pull column  with the quantity fisrt all in the WITZ column, if yes, it will break and return the name of this WHSE WITZ on this column WhseFrom. If no, it willcheck in the other 6 warehouses if we have the minimum quantity following the rules of prioritization in the PULLWH pivot table(p1>p2>p3>p4>p5).

Any help wpuld be very appreciated.

THE OUTPUT should looks like the "Expected Outuout table" shared on the follow example bellow:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Include your expected output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9857631/not-speshal example inserted on the main description above. Please any help or idea would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
priorities = {"ADH": ["WITZ", "ROT", "MAR", "AYC"],
              "AYC": ["WITZ", "ROT"],
              "MAEG": ["ROT", "WITZ"],
              "ROT": ["WITZ", "MAEG", "MAR", "AYC", "ADH"],
              "MAR": ["WITZ", "ROT", "AYC", "ADH"],
              "WITZ": ["ROT", "MAR", "AYC", "ADH"],
              "BUD": ["WITZ", "ROT", "MAR", "AYC", "ADH"]}

def findQty(row):
    #keep only the stores ordered by priority
    stores = row[priorities[row.at["Store"]]]
    #return first store where cumulative sum exceeds pull value
    result = stores[stores.cumsum()>=row.at["Pull"]].index
    if len(result)>0:
        return result[0]
    else:
        return None
        
df["WHSE"] = df.apply(findQty, axis=1)

>>> df[["Store", "WHSE"]]
          Store  WHSE
PNO                   
1084895083   BUD  WITZ
1118952108   AYC   ROT
1119151296   BUD   MAR
1113150401  WITZ   ROT
1118568003  WITZ   AYC
2231065166  MAEG  WITZ
2238179010  MAEG   ROT
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9857631/not-speshal, it is returning it
    KeyError: ("None of [['ROT', 'MAR', 'AYC', 'ADH']] are in the [index]", 'occurred at index 
    0')

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your error. Just ran this code and it works. Please post the output of `print(df.head().to_dict())` so I can check with your `df` format

Comment: It worked now! I did a small modification here. Thanks a lot https://stackoverflow.com/users/9857631/not-speshal ! You helped me a lot!!!!! xD

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9857631/not-speshal Now, once I  run the  code with a lot of rows(more than 30 000 registers), I have this new error: "IndexError: ('index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0', 'occurred at index 30347')" Do you know what should be done ?

Comment: @Yan - Please post a *new* question with the updated inputs and expected output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9857631/not-speshal It was this problem you helped with it some weeks ago. But I`m trying to apply the function with more registers and it is returning this error IndexError

Comment: There is probably no store that has enough quantity. This is a *new* question because your inputs have changed. There is nothing wrong with the logic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9857631/not-speshal Once I print it print(df.head().to_dict(), the output is: (I added an image in the description above)

Comment: The total quantity in all stores is not enough for some product. That's all it means. Any more issues, post a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236854/discussion-between-not-speshal-and-yan).